# Perl module prerequisite not found

Tags: perl

End goal is to install Excel::Writer::XLSX on a server without internet access.

I want to install SUPER as its a prerequisite. Sub::Identify is a prerequisite of SUPER. I believe I installed Sub:Identify successfully. But when I attempt to install SUPER I am prompted that the prerequisite is not installed. Here are the commands I entered on command prompt and the output:

1. `cd Sub-Identify-0.14`
2. `perl MakeFile.pl`
3. `perldoc -l Sub::Identify`
4. Output: `lib\Sub\Identify.pm\`
5. `cd SUPER-1.20141117`
6. perl `Build.PL`
7. Output: `Sub::Identify is not installed`
8. `perl Makefile.PL`
9. Output: `Warning: prerequisite Sub::Identify 0 not found.`

Comment: A server from which I cannot access the internet.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible for you to have a local CPAN mirror on the non-internet server? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44543813/5830574) (to a similar question) describes how to set one up. It's quite easy.

Comment: I edited your comment about the lack of internet access from your server into your question. You can rollback that edit if you prefer or [edit] the question yourself and change it.

Comment: do you have more than one perl installed?  can you show the actual commands you ran to install Sub::Identify and SUPER and their output?  where did you get the things you are installing?  what versions are you installing?

Comment: ok thank you @PerlDuck. i'll doc that as an option. also the Q&A format for personal notes is awesome.

Comment: @ysth **Question1:** i discern only perl 5.14 installed when i `perl -v`. **Question2:** `perl Makefile.PL`. **Question3:** CPAN. **Question4:** Sub-Identify-0.14 and SUPER-1.20141117.

Comment: `perl Makefile.PL` doesn't install anything; edit your question to show your command for installing SUPER and the output

Comment: `Sub-Identify-0.14/lib` is the source module directory. You haven't even built the module yet, let alone installed it.

Comment: Try `cpan .` in `Sub-Identify-0.14` to install from the current directory.

Comment: Ok sorry I've never done this before. I was referencing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541019/manual-installation-of-a-perl-module

Comment: So why did you skip half of the instructions in there (all the `make`/`./Build` parts)?

Comment: Because after `perl makefile.pl` I enter `make`. And the output is that make is not a recognizable command. So I abandoned those instructions after that happened.

Comment: Then you need to install `make`.

Comment: Ok. `make` is a perl module? I tried looking in CPAN and I see File-Info-1.02

Comment: No, `make` is not a Perl module. `perl Makefile.PL` generates a `Makefile` which you then process by issuing the `make` command. If you don't have `make` installed, then install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't install Sub::Identify.

```sh
tar zvzf Sub-Identify-0.14.tar.gz
cd Sub-Identify-0.14
perl MakeFile.pl
make test            # missing
make install         # missing
cd ..

tar zvzf SUPER-1.20141117.tar.gz
cd SUPER-1.20141117
perl Build.PL
./Build.PL test
./Build.PL install
cd ..
```

---

By the way, you could create a mirror of CPAN using [CPAN::Mini](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN::Mini). If you copy this mirror to your offline machine, you could use `cpan` to install modules despite not being online.

Comment: From the comments it seems that `make` isn't installed on the OP's machine. I thought that's _always_ installed?! Unfortunately I cannot remember what package it is part of.

Comment: @PerlDuck, Nah, it's common to not have `make` installed. That's the case for Ubuntu, for example. Just gotta install it. (`apt-get install make` on Ubuntu. Not sure how to do that offline.)

Comment: Hmm. I also suggested a CPAN mirror and the OP liked that idea, but does that work without `make`?

Comment: @PerlDuck, Of course not. `cpan` is not actually an installer. It's a downloader and dependency walker that runs the installers provided by the distros as shown in my answer.

Comment: Ok. Appreciate your patience. I understand what the problem/solution is.